# Aptana Studio build: 3.6.1.201410201044 xdebugger start automatically

Tags: php, aptana, xdebug

I've a problem with the aptana studio. I've created a php drupal project.
now whenever a hint a project url in the browser the aptana start debug automatically. I can't understand from where comes the problems.

Can someone give a hint?

Thks.

Xaver

Answer (score -1):

We can trigger the debugging from Browser with following two methods:

```
1. append the XDEBUG_SESSION_START query parameter
2. set the XDEBUG_SESSION cookie
```

So make sure to clean that query parameter from your url, and clean the cookie as well.